# If X + Y = A + B, and XY = AB, must it be that the set of X,Y is equal to the set of A,B?

Tags: number-theory

I came across this dilemma while solving a CS problem. Can anyone prove what the title mentions?

EDIT: Let's consider only positive integers here

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$(t-X)(t-Y) = (t-A)(t-B)$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following. Where is `t` from and how did you come up with that expression?

Comment: $t$ is an indeterminate.  Expand the two products.